# Spinner can be clicked on top of Navigation menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-spinner, drawerlayout

I have a navigation menu with some items. The problem that I am facing is the Spinner items and other UI elements which is underneath the menu when it is open remains clickable even when the menu is on top of those, as explained in the figure.

[image: error image]

Here is my activity layout files.(activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/delivery_area_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <include layout="@layout/layout_drawer_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my navigation drawer layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_main_navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried to look for solutions and found that for many people setting `android:clickable="true"` does the trick but in my case that is also not working.'

Comment: Hi you can close spinner when navigation drawer is open.put code login inside activity class

Comment: spinner is not the only problem, there will be other views also. That's why I was looking for proper solution.

Comment: You can use fragment class and use spinner control inside fragment layout. problem with activity_layout